# Zipping file with DotNetZip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am trying to zip and encrypt a chosen file from the user. Everything works fine except that I am zipping the whole path, i.e not the file itself. Below is my code, any help on how I can zip and encrypt on the chosen file.

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
var fileName = string.Format(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "test1";
    zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zip.AddFile(fileName);
    zip.Save(path + "\\test.ZIP");
    MessageBox.Show("File Zipped!", "Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `C:\Temp\file.ext` is zipped as `\Temp\file.ext` instead of just `file.ext`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I don't know `DotNetZip` as I use another ZIP library, but isn't there also an overload which takes the filename? EDIT: See the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the file name explicitly for the zip-archive:

```
zip.AddFile(fileName).FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

Comment: Seems kinda lame... There is a method called AddFile(string fileName) but you have to specify the FileName property of its return value to make it work?!?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can zip up a file, and rename it within the archive . Upon extraction, a file will be created with the new name.

```
using (ZipFile zip1 = new ZipFile())
{
   string newName= fileToZip + "-renamed";
   zip1.AddFile(fileToZip).FileName = newName; 
   zip1.Save(archiveName);
}
```

Reference : [C# Examples](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples)